# How do you check if a html Meta tag exist using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have the following Meta tag in the header of my HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta property="article:tag" content="This is an apple" />
    <meta property="article:tag" content="This is a pear" />
</head>
```

And I would like to check if the meta tag with the content **"this is an apple"** exists. But for some reason My alert box always runs true.

```
if (document.querySelectorAll('meta[content="This is an apple"]') != null) {
  alert('Its here!');
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: use the length property on result from querySelectorAll instead of checking if its null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will always return true because `querySelectorAll` return an empty array in case of 0 match. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

> You can use the length property of the NodeList object to determine the number of elements that matches the specified selector

try this:

```js
if (document.querySelectorAll('meta[content="This is not an apple"]').length > 0) {
    alert('Its here!');
} else {
    alert('Its not here')
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta property="article:tag" content="This is an apple" />
    <meta property="article:tag" content="This is a pear" />
</head>
```

Comment: I appreciate the detail. You're solution worked great!

Answer (score 3):

`document.querySelectorAll` returns an array. You want to check for its length, because if there are no matching elements, it returns `[]` (the empty array). So:

```
if (document.querySelectorAll('meta[content="This is an apple"]').length !== 0) {
    alert('Its here!');
}
```